# PowerShell cmdlet to set Control Panel items?

Tags: windows, powershell, powershell-cmdlet, controlpanel, control-panel

Is there any cmdlet that sets values in the Windows Control Panel? I'm thinking of something like a "Set-ControlPanelItem" to go along with "Get-ControlPanelItem"
and "Show-ControlPanelItem"

If not, why didn't Microsoft include a "set" functionality for the Windows Control Panel?

Thank you!

Comment: Can someone explain why this question has been downvoted? It seems to be a relevant programming question.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem to show any reasearch effort, there is no `Set-ControlPanelItem` cmdlet. What do you actually try to achieve? Making changes to the system works with many different cmdlets. As for your second question: There is no one true answer to that based on facts. As I said before, if you want to make changes to the system you need to use many different cmdlets.

Comment: I answered my own question after researching more. I thought that other programmers diving into Powershell for the first time would be helped by this same question. Didn't know it is so important to research heavily before posting.

Answer (score -2):

It's not helpful to think about getting and setting Control Panel items. Powershell gives you access to the underlying OS and the way to have the same effect as changing Control Panel items is using wmiobject. (and maybe other cmdlets too)